# Android N warning against .so file having W+E segments

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, shared-libraries, .so

`{.so filename} has W+E (writable and executable) load segments. This is a security risk shared libraries with W+E load segments will not be supported in a future Android release. Please fix the library.` 
How can this be fixed?

Comment: What tool-chain are you using that produces W+E segments (so I can avoid it)?

Comment: @RichardCritten I'm building the .so using ndk-build. The above warning appears when the app loads the .so.

Comment: See this section _"Text Relocations (Enforced since API 23)"_ in http://android-developers.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/android-changes-for-ndk-developers.html

Comment: @RichardCritten That didn't help.

Comment: Hi,  did you fix this?